# PHPによるGoogle APIを用いたWebアプリがPHP Fatal errorを返すようになりました

Tags: php, ssl

昨年2017年末に開発し、今年1月から3月まで動作していたGoogle APIを用いたWebアプリが
突然PHP Fatal errorを返すようになりました。
クライアントからは`500 - 内部サーバー エラー`として表示されます。
サーバー側で動作させると下記エラーとなります。

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Error creating resource:
[message] fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
[file] D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php 
[line] 287
[message] fopen(): Failed to enable crypto
[file] D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php 
[line] 287
[message] fopen(https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token): failed to open stream: operation failed
[file] D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php 
[line] 287' in
D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php:227 Stack trace: #0
D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php(291): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createResource(Object(Closure)) #1 
D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php(52): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createStream in 
D:\inetpub\ogads\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 51
```

発生しているソースは
「はじめてのアナリティクス API: ウェブ アプリケーション向け PHP クイック スタート」
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php?hl=ja
の`index.php/oauth2callback.php`で試しても同じエラーとなりました。
上記URLのソースはWebアプリを作成する際に参考にしたソースです。

「ソースは未修正」／「チュートリアルソースでも発生」のため、サーバー環境でしょうか。
エラーを見る限りGoogle側のファイルがSSL認証を拒否しているように見えるため
お手上げです。どなたかわかる方がいらっしゃれば、ご助言お願いします。

Comment: curlを利用してサーバからGoogleの対象のURLを参照することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。CURLは使用したことがありませんが、試してみます。

Comment: 補足しますと、curlでとれないとなるとサーバーもしくはgoogleの問題、curlで取れればPHPもしくはライブラリの問題と切り分けるためです

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。問題点きりわけのため

Comment: 新規に検証用サーバーを構築して検証しましたが結果は変わらず。サーバー環境ではなさそうです。（WindowsServer2012R2/WindwosServer2016両者試しましたが変わらず）PHPは5.6を使用しなければならないため現行の5.6.32から、最新と思われる5.6.34に変えてみましたがこちらも変化なし。ご助言いただきましたCURLを導入してエラー表示されていたGoogleのhttps URL「https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token」を参照してみましたが、結果は 「not found」でした。念のためGoogleに新規プロジェクトを作成して新たな認証情報を作成、client_secrets.jsonを入れ替えたり、GoogleのPHP用SDK最新版を落として試すなども実施しましたが、エラーは変わりませんでした。

Comment: すみません自己解決しました。エラーがPHPのOPEN_SSL関係のため、PHP.INIの[openssl]にopenssl.cafileとopenssl.capathを、[curl]のopenssl.cafileを追加したところ、エラーが出なくなりました。いままでこの設定なしで3月中旬まで動いていたのに・・・。とりあえずこれで様子を見ます。ご助言/ご協力ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決してよかったですね。自己解決した場合は是非自己回答をしてください。https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1747/

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。PHPのOPEN_SSL関係のため、PHP.INIの[openssl]にopenssl.cafileとopenssl.capathを、[curl]のopenssl.cafileを追加したところ、エラーが出なくなりました。